# What are the differences between Splatoon Testfire and Global Testfire?

Tags: version-differences, splatoon

What are the differences between Splatoon Testfire and Global Testfire? I can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the Splatoon Wiki](http://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Splatoon_Testfire#Differences_from_the_Global_Testfire):

> **Differences from the Global Testfire**
>
> There were various small differences from the Global Testfire version.
>
> - The Global Testfire demo has a different icon from the current demo.
> - The title screen no longer shows "pre-purchase" and now shows
>   "purchase" as the game has already been released.
> - The Global Testfire demo is 6 MB larger than the current demo.

It looks like the "Testfire" main difference was it's release date, as the original (Global) was an open demo to test the servers, but the latter one was just for promotion of the game.

Comment: Thanks. That extra information is very helpful. Do you happen to know if the later (Testfire) demo was released after, with or before the normal game?

Comment: It was released after the normal game was released.  The only thing I do not know is if the Testfire group joined the same servers like that regular players at the time. (as in Free and Paid players could end up in the same game together.)  Based on the previous demo, I have to assume the two where separated.

Comment: Just to make sure: Global Testfire was release before the normal game?

Comment: Correct, the Global Testfire was released a whole two (and a half) weeks before the release of Splatoon.  The Testfire was released three months afterwards.